# $routeProvider causing me problems

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Here is the Angular code I am trying to run:

```
var ticketRegister = angular.module('ticketRegister', []);   

function changeMode($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/Calculator', {
    controller: ticketCalculatorController,
    templateUrl: 'Calculator.html'
  }).when('/DB', {
    controller: ticketDBController,
    templateUrl: 'DB.html'
  }).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
  });
}

ticketRegister.config(changeMode);
```

Here is the html:

```
<div ng-view>
   <a href="#/Calculator">Calculator</a>
</div>
```

When I click on the link, all it does it take me to `/#/Calculator`

I figured I'd toss this question out to the Stack Overflow community to get some fresh eyes on the matter because mine...are....well, tired  :p

Oh, and this is being hosted on a web server.

Comment: Do you get any JavaScript errors or anything?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all.  It just simply follows the normal functioning of the link.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it turns out I didn't have the ng-app directive anywhere on my index.html.  I apologize for wasting everybody's time cause there's no way anyone could've seen that because I didn't post all of my code, just the parts I thought were relevant.

```
Sorry!
```

EDIT:  Still having the same exact issue even after I added the ng-app directive.  Reposting question...

Comment: You should be able to delete your question

Comment: I'm looking around but I can't find a way to delete this question.